# Change color of spinner items to 2 colors

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-dialogfragment

I have populated my **Spinner**, which appears in **DialogFragment**, with two lists - *list1* and *list2*. I want that the lists appear in two different colors: i.e. list1 in blue and list2 in red, during dropdown.
How can I achieve this dynamically?

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

    Spinner spin;
    spin = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Material 1");
    list.add("Material 2");
    list.add("Material 3");
    list.add("Material 4");
    list.add("Material 5");
    list.add("Material 6");

    //Second List
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("Mat 7");
    list2.add("Mat 8");
    list2.add("Mat 9");

    //Combined List
    List<String> listCombine = new ArrayList<String>();
    listCombine.addAll(list);
    listCombine.addAll(list2);

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listCombine); 

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    builder
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setView(view)
    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way is to create a custom Adapter to use two different layouts: one red and one blue. You will need to override these three methods:

- [`getViewTypeCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) to return 2 to tell the Adapter to expect two different row layouts.
- [`getItemViewType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) to return whether this row is in the first List or second.
- [`getDropDownView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getDropDownView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) to call `getItemViewType()` and use the appropriate layout.

Or you could override `getDropDownView()` by itself to change the appropriate color(s).